# Solid javascript encode uri

Tags: javascript, url, encode

I've read this and more articles:

[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Still I have not found a solid encode/decode uri solution.

**Let's say I have these variables**

```
var first = 'Hello&and';
var second = "Let's have cite";
var third = 'And "hash,.#$';
var fourth = 'åäö other strange chars';
```

An unencoded url would be:

```
var url 'http://example.com/?first=' + first + '&second=' + second + '&third=' + third + '&fourth=' + fourth;
```

Later it should be in an ajax request like:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url );
```

I tried this:

```
var url 'http://example.com/?first=' + encodeURIComponent(first);
```

But it does not work with `#`. So what is a solid encoding solution for all characters?

I don't use jQuery, just javascript.

Comment: As i understand `encodeURIComponent` is for params.. And the `encodeURI` is for the URL... http://i.imgur.com/2xKpYd0.png In your case the `#` should use `encodeURIComponent` (%23) When you say it doesnt work, what do you mean ?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific about what "does not work with `#`" means: `encodeURIComponent('And "hash,.#$')` → `"And%20%22hash%2C.%23%24"`.

Comment: Have you tried using `escape()` ?

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan do not use escape, The escape and unescape functions are deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `encodeURIComponent` when encoding uri parameters. When you encode a hashtag with that function it will result in the string "%23".

So in your example:

```
var first = 'Hello&and';
var second = "Let's have cite";
var third = 'And "hash,.#$';
var fourth = 'åäö other strange chars';
var url = 'http://example.com/?first=' + encodeURIComponent(first) + '&second=' + encodeURIComponent(second) + '&third=' + encodeURIComponent(third) + '&fourth=' + encodeURIComponent(fourth);
```

Will result in the url variable containing the string:

```
http://example.com/?first=Hello%26and&second=Let's%20have%20cite&third=And%20%22hash%2C.%23%24&fourth=%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6%20other%20strange%20chars
```

More information of the `encodeURIComponent` function can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).

> (citation from w3 school) This function encodes special characters. In
>   addition, it encodes the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

Comment: Is it solid in every case with every input? or is it breakable?

Comment: That W3S citation is terrible. "Special characters in addition to <a bunch of special characters>". What is a "special" character?! Better quote MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @Jens The function is designed so you can transport any arbitrary value as part of the URL. So, yes, it is solid. Unless you can prove otherwise...

Answer (score -2):

You can try using `escape()` function. This has saved me many-a times.

`escape('#')` does yield `%23`.

Comment: The escape and unescape functions are deprecated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features